# MySQL HA_ERR_LOCK_WAIT_TIMEOUT ignoring innodb_lock_wait_timeout (deleting most of a table)

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.6, python

I am issuing some long-running delete queries to some databases, and I am getting the following error:

```
Last_Error: Could not execute Write_rows event on table DATABASE.TABLENAME; Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction, Error_code: 1205; handler error HA_ERR_LOCK_WAIT_TIMEOUT; the event's master log mysql-bin.005698, end_log_pos 91495479
```

I have set "innodb_lock_wait_timeout" to high value such as the query will never hit the timeout.

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.innodb_lock_wait_timeout;
+-----------------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.innodb_lock_wait_timeout |
+-----------------------------------+
|                           1000000 |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Any suggestions for how to avoid this error? I need to delete large amounts of data so I want to issue queries in a loop without supervision. It feels a bit like a mysql bug. MySQL version is 5.6.

EDIT: Here's the exact query. The data is sharded client-side based on the function shown (`MOD(MOD(user_id,65536), shard_count) != shard_id)`. The majority of the data in the DBs shouldn't be there, so the delete is big, and it's cascading down to tables that are >300GB (where each user might have an inventory of 200 items, for example)

```
DELETE FROM User
WHERE account_type = "type1"
AND
user_id IN (
    SELECT b.user_id
    FROM (
        SELECT a.account_type, a.user_id
        FROM (
            SELECT account_type, user_id
            FROM User
            WHERE account_type = "type1"
            AND
            MOD(MOD(user_id,65536), 20) != 9
            LIMIT 1000000
        ) a
    ) b
)
```

EDIT: As requested, output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE User \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: User
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `User` (
  `account_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `mod_date_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `team_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `shard_key` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`account_type`,`user_id`),
  KEY `PLAY_SHKEY_I` (`shard_key`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

EDIT: I believe at this point that it was down to a programming error, because I wasn't calling `commit()` from the python client until a really big loop completed, so I think there was a huge ongoing transaction that did not commit ever (because it never made it all the way through the loop)

Comment: Did you set the global innodb_lock_wait_timeout before thread that hit the timeout was created?

Comment: What do your queries look like exactly? Can you provide some examples?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE User`.

Comment: Please explain the Replication topology.  It sounds like you have "multi-source replication"?

Answer (score 1):

Do *not* use `OFFSET` when looping through to do `DELETEs`; it is likely to get slower and slower, and maybe hit even your increased timeout.

Try not to put all the deletes in a single transaction.  Instead make it so that if one delete dies, rerunning the deletes will still work 'correctly'.

Don't delete more than 1000 rows at a time.

More discussion of "big deletes":  [MySQL Big DELETEs](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig)

**Deleting 95% of a table**

Now that you have explained more of what is going on, I recommend [*rebuilding the table*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_more_than_half_a_table) by creating a new table and copying over the 5%.  (This technique applies for any percentage, but its benefits are dubious if copying more than 50%.)

Note that `innodb_file_per_table` needs to have been on before the bloated table was build, else you won't recoup the disk space.

If that would tie up the table too long, then walk through the `PRIMARY KEY` in chunks of 1K rows, deleting about 95% of each chunk.  (As discussed elsewhere in that link.)  You won't be able to return the disk space to the OS (without a locking `OPTIMIZE TABLE`), but the "freed" space will eventually be used by new `INSERTs`.

Comment: Rick - Check out updated question.

Comment: Doesn't `MOD(MOD(user_id,65536), 20) != 9` pick 95% of the users??  Maybe you meant `=9` in order to get only 5%?  What does "shard" mean?  If it is referring to 20 servers, then please explain that.  _Then_ the `!=9` means "all the users who don't belong on this machine"??

Comment: @RickJames correct - to give a little context, we scaled out from 1 shard to 20 (well, 1-> 3 -> 20) with the sharding function shown. However, each shard was bootstrapped with 100% of the data. Hence this effort to clean up (as you mentioned) 95% of data on each shard. I changed/removed some column names (due to paranoia); these DBs store state for some games which recently took on millions of new users.

Comment: @ArthurMencke - OK, Copy over the good stuff.  (See my addition.)

Comment: We considered this approach, but the DB nodes we are purging need to continue replicating from the masters (which serve live requests). Therefore, deleting the bad data will not break replication (since the shard function ensures requests will never change the data we are deleting, but will change/add data which belongs and remains untouched by the deletion queries). It may be possible to copy the good data and replay the binlogs from the appropriate offset afterwards, but this I think requires more mysql experience than I bring

Comment: Luckily we have `innodb_file_per_table` enabled, so my hope is after purging data is complete, I can issue a `ALTER TABLE <tablename>
ENGINE = InnoDB` to reclaim disk space

Comment: @ArthurMencke - I don't see the problem.  You go to one shard; stop replication; purge the table by whatever means, but _with replication turned off for the purge thread_ (see something like `SQL_BINLOG = OFF`); turn replication back on.

Answer (score 0):

You probably hit this issue because you are running multiple delete transactions at the same time and some of these delete queries are trying to lock the same rows and they are waiting for each other.

Try to not delete the same rows in different transactions at the same time.

If you share the schema and the queries I could give you more advises.

Also there is a tool called [pt-archiver](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/3.0/pt-archiver.html) which can archive/delete large amount of data from a table without any issues.